# Media asset management solution php, mysql, cloud

Tags: php, mysql, cloud, assets

I'm looking for a media asset management solution which is ...

- free/opensource
- runs preferetly on php, mysql
- stores assets in the cloud.
- has customizable rights for usergroups and assets
- cdn distribution of low resolution resized images for specific web-page.
- high resolution images accessible through publishing solution
- access restrictions
- good integration possibilities in a php js web application (rest/php api)
- manage uploads & select uploaded products and assign them
- rest / js integration in front-end
- nice userinterface with high usability

Any recommendations for solutions?

Thanks for your hints! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: drupal is not suitable for me. I only need the media asset management part for storing pictures and movies, uploading them to s3. In most cases I wont even need to let the user select from the asset database. In some cases I might neet this feature as well.  ... and distributing them through a cdn / making the high resolutions pictures available to a publishing solution. This must be easily integratable in php/zend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it covers all your needs, but have you investigated ResourceSpace? http://www.resourcespace.org/